# Doctrine get single latest row of Detail for each Master

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, greatest-n-per-group, query-builder

I have QueryBuilder like this

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
  ->createQueryBuilder()
  ->select('partial master.{id,name}, partial detail.{id,name}')
  ->from('AppBundle:Master', 'master')
  ->leftJoin('master.detail', 'detail')
  ->orderBy('detail.id','DESC')
  ->getQuery();
return $query->getArrayResult();
```

master relation is OneToMany, detail relation is ManyToOne.
I'm trying to get a single row of detail with detail id is higher or lower. What Querybuilder to make this possible?
example I have data like this:

```
1.A, 1.B, 1.C, 2.A, 3.A, 3.C
```

I want Result like this below

```
1.A, 2.A, 3.A
```

Comment: did you tried `getSingleResult()` ?

Comment: dont like this. Here I have been edited my question and give example. @MertÖksüz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine Query Language get Max/Latest Row Per Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106582/doctrine-query-language-get-max-latest-row-per-group)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('master.id, master.name, detail.id, detail.name')
    ->from('AppBundle:Master', 'master')
    ->leftJoin('master.detail', 'detail')
    ->groupBy('master.id')
    ->orderBy('detail.id','DESC')
    ->getQuery()
;

return $query->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: i can't use groupBy, if the detail name has 2 different value, i'm still get 2 detail. @rendyEkoPrastiyo

Comment: Your question tells `I'm trying to get a single row of detail.`, now you want `if the detail name has 2 different value, i'm still get 2 detail.`, what do you mean?

Comment: if i use groupBy with the detail name has 2 different value, i'm still get 2 detail.
I want only get single row with specified detail id.
example with higher detail id or lower detail id. @rendy@EkoPrastiyo

Comment: Could you give the result of `dump($query->getArrayResult()` of my query above?

Comment: yes. 
but not yet like i mean.
dont like this. Here I have been edited my quetion and give example. @rendyEkoPrastiyo

Comment: Do not use `partial` in your select. Doctrine doc says `The partial object problem in general does not apply to methods or queries where you do not retrieve the query result as objects. Examples are: Query#getArrayResult(), Query#getScalarResult(), Query#getSingleScalarResult(), etc.` [Partial Objects](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html). I have updated the answer, could you give a try?

Comment: I use partial becauce i dont need other field, and partial can do right i wanted. so how to get detail id with higher or lower id? @rendyEkoPrastiyo

Comment: If you want array result, you can't use partial. That's Doctrine's law. If you don't want other fields, or only select some fields, you can use `$queryBuilder->select('table.field1, table.field2')`, that would select only the fields you requested.

Comment: okay, so how i would filter detail id with higher or lower id? @rendyEkoPrastiyo

Comment: `orderBy('detail.id','DESC')` on the example is for descending ordering of `detail` by `id`. You may change it to fit your need.

Comment: cant to be simple like that.
If parent have 2 or 3 detail, I only need 1 detail with id higher or lower.
@rendyEkoPrastiyo

Comment: Have you tried before complaining? `orderBy('detail.id','DESC')` will sort details from highest ID to lowest one, and `groupBy('master.id')` is responsible for making sure that only a single detail is displayed on each master. Therefore, only a single detail with highest ID per master is selected.

Comment: yes, i have tried. only using `groupBy('master.id')` i get single detail with result detail id lower, but i cant get with highest detail ID. `orderBy('detail.id','DESC')` only sort result from `groupBy('master.id')`. @rendyEkoPrastiyo

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest detail for each master row you ca use following DQL

```
SELECT m,a 
FROM AppBundle\Entity\Master m
    LEFT JOIN m.detail a
    LEFT JOIN AppBundle\Entity\Detail b 
    WITH a.master = b.master 
    AND a.id < b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```